# Invalid il code System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.OpenRead() Method body is empty

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I 'am implementing an android app using Xamarin and MVVMCross. Inside my PCL I have a ZipUtility class and the following method:

```
public NoDataResponse UnCompressZipFile(string path, string filename)
   {
       NoDataResponse response = new NoDataResponse();
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       sb.AppendLine(string.Format("\r\nUnzipping '{0}' in '{1}' folder...", filename, path));

       try
       {       


           using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(filename, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
           {
               foreach (System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
               {
                   if (entry.FullName.EndsWith(".txt", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                   {
                       System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(filename, path);
                       break;
                   }
               }
           }


           response.IsCallSuccessful = true;
           sb.AppendLine(string.Format("\r\nFinished Unzipping file {0}.\r\n", filename));

           response.BusinessEntityMessage = sb.ToString();
       }

       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           response.IsCallSuccessful = false;
           response.BusinessEntityMessage = "\r\nUNZIPPING ERROR: " + ex.Message + "\r\n";
       }

       return response;
   }
```

The ZipFile Class inside my method is part of the System.IO.Compression (System.IO.Compression.FileSystem namespace).

When I execute the method I get the following error:

System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.IO.Compression.ZipFile:Open (string,System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode): method body is empty.
at HHT.Core.Globals.ZipUtility.UnCompressZipFile (System.String path, System.String filename) [0x00033] in c:\Sandbox\HHT-ANDROID\HHTApp\HHT.Core\Globals\ZipUtility.cs:32

I'm not sure what is missing because the same code was working perfectly before inside the PCL.

I have also tried to run the same class using dependency injection (N=31 slodge) from my DROIDUI project and still get the same error.

I would appreciate any comments or ideas on this.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're deploying a reference assembly to your Android device (a reference assembly is only for the compilation and thus doesn't contain IL).

Which version of `System.IO.Compression` are you using? I assume you're using the `Microsoft.Bcl.Compression` NuGet package?

Our NuGet package doesn't provide an implementation for Android. In fact we only ship an implementation for Windows Phone -- for all other platforms we use the one that ships with the platform.

I'm not sure whether Xamarin supports the System.IO.Compression.dll (which includes ZipArchive). The reason it may have worked previously is because you retargeted the PCL after installing the NuGet package.

Comment: I would like to thank you so much for your comments. Actually you solved my problem. I was providing a reference assembly as you speculated. As soon as I referenced the System.IO.Compression from C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework it worked.Thank you so much again.

Comment: You're welcome. That doesn't sound like the correct fix though -- you shouldn't directly add references to a platform implementation as this might break other scenarios. However, if this fixed your problem than it sounds like a bug on Xamarin's side. A better temporary workaround would be continue to use the NuGet package from the PCL and making sure your app doesn't deploy the System.IO.Compression.dll.

Comment: I have updated yesterday to the newest Xamarin Android version and my ZipArchive class got me  System.NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented. I dont know if the previous version of Xamarin Android I was using was having a bug by allowing the class to be fully functional. When you say to continue using the Nuget Package you mean the Microsoft.Bcl.Compression correct? To be honest I havent used that one yet but as you said you only ship implementation for Windows Phone so it wont even allow me to install it from Nuget.

Comment: I have removed all the platform specific dlls and I will use whatever objects pcl is providing. Unfortunately now I have to build an archiving mechanism from scratch.

Comment: The NuGet package only contains an implementation for Windows Phone, but it enables you to consume the platform specific implementation in a portable fashion. We ship ZipArchive in two platforms (.NET 4.5 & Windows Store). With NuGet package that set expands to Windows Phone. Once Xamarin implemented it, it should automatically be consumable in a PCL via the NuGet package as well. Let me ping Miguel to see what they are thinking about supporting compression.

Comment: **Update**: [Miguel is investigating](https://twitter.com/migueldeicaza/status/424968979929907200).

Comment: Thank you very much Immo and Miguel. I will be waiting for your feedback.

Comment: **Update**: ZipArchive is indeed [missing from Mono](https://twitter.com/migueldeicaza/status/426172383230033920). No ETA yet, but they are looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your findings so far, I bet you'll be able to fix the error by copying the [Xamarin.Android System.IO.Compression.dll from the Mac installer](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/41185/#Comment_41185) into:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\

This assembly is currently (accidentally) missing from the Xamarin.Android Windows installer. A bug has been filed about this, so the assembly should be present by default in a future release.

If this doesn't work, be sure to report back that result so we can investigate further!

Comment: Hi Brendan. I have referenced the contents of the zip file you attached in the Xamarin Developers site in my DroidUI project and still the same issue. System.NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented.at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive..ctor (System.IO.Stream stream) [0x00000] at System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.Open (System.String archiveFileName, ZipArchiveMode mode, System.Text.Encoding entryNameEncoding) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 }

Comment: Oh shoot! Yes indeed. The problem is simpler than I thought, and Immo was exactly right: [ZipArchive has not yet been implemented in Mono](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.IO.Compression/ZipArchive.cs).